# React How to back to previous page with filters still in place

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Having a hard time trying to figure this out.

I Have 2 Components

1. A filter component & A table view component
2. A enhanced view of number table view with more info and functionality

From component  2 i want to go back to component 1 but have the filters still in place?

How can i acheive this?

I've tried

this.props.history.push('/1');

It goes back but doesn't keep the filters?

```
export default class FilterComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {name:[]}
    }
    

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(
                (data) => data.map(e => 
                      this.setState({name:[...this.state.name,  e.id]})
                  ))
    }




    onTrigger = (event) => {
        this.props.parentCallback(event.target.value);
        event.preventDefault();
        
    }

   

    render() {

        if(this.state.name.length < 1) {

            return (
                <div>
                <p1> Loadings</p1>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div className="contactfForm">
    <select onChange={this.onTrigger}>
        <option> ID </option>
        {this.state.name.map((result)=>(<option title={result}>{result}</option>))}
    </select>
```

Comment: what are `filters` in your context?

Comment: @RameshReddy 3 Select boxes with data coming from an API

Comment: how is the state of these checkboxes handled? Is it persisted anywhere? Add related code to the question

Comment: how does you state look like? do you use redux? internal state or something else? well need to see some code to give you a better explanation.

Comment: @RameshReddy please see state

Comment: You mean the url query parameters? Have you tried `window.location.search` ? `this.props.history.push('/1' + location.search)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are rendering the filters twice, inside component1 and again inside component2. If you want to navigate and preserve the state, you have two react-based options, and a JS one:

**MOVING FILTERS OUTSIDE ROUTER SWITCHER**

If you render the filters outside the Switcher of the router, when changing route only the component1 and component2 will rerender, but not the filters.

**STORING FILTERS STATE IN A GLOBAL STATE**

If rendering the filters outside the Switcher of your Router is not feasible (Because maybe the filters are not rendered in every page of your app) you could save the filter state in a global state (Using for example, React Contexts, see https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html; or Redux).

If you use React Contexts, you could create the provider ouside the router, and inside the Filters component retrieve and modify its values. This way you will mantain the state between components.

**SAVING FILTER STATE IN LOCAL STORAGE**

If you want to preserve the state also when refreshing the page, you could store the filter state in the Local Storage of the Browser. Every time the Filters component is rendered, you would retrieve the value from the Local Storage, and every time the filters are modified, you would save it. That will also make that when changing the page, as the Local Storage is mantained, the filter state is mantained too.

Comment: I like the last one is there any recommended docs for this? or could you show me how it would look like please

Comment: You can refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage. Local storage works with strings, so you will have to stringify (`JSON.stringify(filters)`) when saving and parse (`var filters = JSON.parse(filtersString)`) when retrieving.